# How can I save an "Auto model" from rapid miner to local disk

Tags: rapidminer

I have built a regression model using Rapid Miner. After fine tuning the model the precision is good. Now I want to use the same Model file to run on next set of data. Is there any way to Export RapidMiner classifier model to local disk and to predict on new data.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `python` or `scikit-learn` - kindly do not spam the tags (removed).

Comment: The fact that you may need help in a sorting algorithm that is subsequently to be used in a spaceship does not make the question related to `space-engineering`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get access to the AutoModel result, you click on "Open Process" in the result view. Then you can either right click on the third output port (for the model) or re-run the process and then store the model by right-clicking on the model tab header.

In general, you can store any model in your RapidMiner repository. Either by right-clicking on the tab header in the result view, or by using the *"Store"* operator after the model output port.

If you then want to run the model on new data you use the *"Apply Model"* operator, with the stored model and the new data set.

See the tutorial process for an example (just copy & paste the XML in your process window).
You can also check the RapidMiner community for more training material:
 https://community.rapidminer.com/t5/Machine-Learning-Essentials-K-nn/tkb-p/IntroductoryML

[image: Apply Model tutorial process]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><process version="9.0.003">
 <context>
<input/>
<output/>
<macros/>
</context>
<operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="6.0.002" expanded="true" name="Process" origin="GENERATED_TUTORIAL">
<process expanded="true">
  <operator activated="true" class="retrieve" compatibility="9.0.003" expanded="true" height="68" name="Retrieve Polynomial" origin="GENERATED_TUTORIAL" width="90" x="112" y="85">
    <parameter key="repository_entry" value="//Samples/data/Polynomial"/>
  </operator>
  <operator activated="true" class="split_data" compatibility="9.0.003" expanded="true" height="103" name="Split Data" origin="GENERATED_TUTORIAL" width="90" x="246" y="85">
    <enumeration key="partitions">
      <parameter key="ratio" value="0.8"/>
      <parameter key="ratio" value="0.2"/>
    </enumeration>
  </operator>
  <operator activated="true" class="select_attributes" compatibility="9.0.003" expanded="true" height="82" name="Select Attributes" origin="GENERATED_TUTORIAL" width="90" x="447" y="289">
    <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="single"/>
    <parameter key="attribute" value="label"/>
    <parameter key="invert_selection" value="true"/>
    <parameter key="include_special_attributes" value="true"/>
  </operator>
  <operator activated="true" class="linear_regression" compatibility="9.0.003" expanded="true" height="103" name="Linear Regression" origin="GENERATED_TUTORIAL" width="90" x="447" y="85"/>
  <operator activated="true" class="apply_model" compatibility="7.1.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Apply Model" origin="GENERATED_TUTORIAL" width="90" x="715" y="187">
    <list key="application_parameters"/>
  </operator>
  <connect from_op="Retrieve Polynomial" from_port="output" to_op="Split Data" to_port="example set"/>
  <connect from_op="Split Data" from_port="partition 1" to_op="Linear Regression" to_port="training set"/>
  <connect from_op="Split Data" from_port="partition 2" to_op="Select Attributes" to_port="example set input"/>
  <connect from_op="Select Attributes" from_port="example set output" to_op="Apply Model" to_port="unlabelled data"/>
  <connect from_op="Linear Regression" from_port="model" to_op="Apply Model" to_port="model"/>
  <connect from_op="Apply Model" from_port="labelled data" to_port="result 2"/>
  <connect from_op="Apply Model" from_port="model" to_port="result 1"/>
  <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
  <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
  <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
  <portSpacing port="sink_result 3" spacing="0"/>
  <description align="center" color="green" colored="true" height="189" resized="true" width="210" x="391" y="23">Generating a model within the training of a linear regression</description>
  <description align="center" color="blue" colored="true" height="188" resized="true" width="309" x="74" y="23">Loading labelled data</description>
  <description align="center" color="purple" colored="true" height="187" resized="true" width="208" x="390" y="250">Unlabelled data&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;Removing the label to emulate an unlabelled data set.</description>
  <description align="left" color="yellow" colored="false" height="305" resized="true" width="325" x="645" y="134">Applying the model obtained from training to an unlabelled data set&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;Labelled data output:&lt;br&gt;ExampleSet from the unlabelled input port enriched with predictions obtained from applying the model.&lt;br&gt;Model output:&lt;br&gt;Have a look into the Results view showing the formula for linear regression with coefficients obtained from the training process.&lt;br&gt; 
 </description>
 </process>
 </operator>
 </process>
```

Comment: And how to use that model with retrieve function?